# Are there any specific rules about how to prepare spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, spellcasting, rests

[This question is related to my Dwarven Cleric character.]

In the *Player's Handbook*, it says that all spells need to be prepared in advance before they can be used. I get that this is done while resting but does it matter how long the rest is (i.e. long or short) as it doesn't seem to say how long each spell takes to prepare.

Also, are there any specific mechanisms for preparing spells, other than telling my DM "In this rest I will prepare X spells"?

Comment: If you're referencing a different question, you should link to it. Thats the assumption im making based on the first line

Comment: Have you read the rules on Spellcasting and Preparing spells for your specific class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are both answered directly in the rules. The last paragraph under "Preparing and Casting Spells" in the Cleric class in the [Basic Rules](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules) or p.58 of the PHB states:

> You can change your list of prepared spells **when you finish a long rest**. Preparing a new list of cleric spells requires time spent in prayer and meditation: at least **1 minute per spell level for each spell on your list**.

To your first question, no, you cannot change your prepared spells after a short rest.

To your second, there is a *little* more to it then just telling your GM which spells you're preparing as you must also spend some small amount of in-game time.

Comment: Okay thank you, I must have missed those pages.